# Install module Snowball Stemmer with composer and required library

Tags: 8, search, composer

I need a german Stemmer processor for my Search API in Drupal 8. [Snowball Stemmer](https://www.drupal.org/project/snowball_stemmer) seems to be the right choice, but I can't get it to work. Snowball Stemmer requires a library. I think it is the wamania/php-stemmer.

It should be installed with composer but I am not familiar with composer.

I tried following:

```
composer require drupal/snowball_stemmer
```

But I am getting

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                 
 Could not find package drupal/snowball_stemmer at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

I tried also:

```
composer require drupal/snowball_stemmer --dev --ignore-platform-reqs
```

but getting the same error.

How I can install Snowball Stemmer with a german library?